# C# store app: Updating a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, async-await

I'm developing a Windows store App.

I have

```
class User
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Enabled { get; set; }

    public User(string Login)
    {
        this.Login = Login;
        this.Load();
    }

    async public Task Load()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await App.http.GetAsync("https://example.com/user?login=" + Login);
        var xml = XDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        var user = (from entry in xml.Descendants("user")
                        select new
                        {
                            Name       = (string)entry.Element("name"),
                            Enabled    = (string)entry.Element("enabled")
                        }).First();
        this.Name = user.Name;
        this.Enabled = user.Enabled;
    }
}
```

that describes user and loads all data asynchronously from the server. I also have MainPage.xaml with the following code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Mail.Common.LayoutAwarePage
{        
    ObservableCollection<User> Users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            
        itemListView.ItemsSource = Users;
    }

    private async void pageRoot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await App.http.GetAsync("https://example.com/listusers");
        var xml = XDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        foreach (var item in from entry in xml.Descendants("email")
                             select new
                             {
                                 Login = (string)entry.Element("name")
                             })
        {
            Users.Add(new User(item.Login));
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage` has a `ListView` that diplays `ObservableCollection<User> Users`. (I have DataTemplate that looks like:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="470" Height="85">
            <Border Height="40" Width="40" Margin="10,10,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Login}" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Semilight" 
                   Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="320" Height="26" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="320" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Enabled}" FontSize="16" Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

).

Unfortunately, **I see only initial data (logins) in the list**. All other data that's received asynchronously in the constructor (`name`, `enabled`) is not shown in the `listview` (I'm sure, it is loaded correctly).

How can I make `ListView` to show actual state of objects in `Users` collection? Or should I perform synchronous requests (how?)

Comment: Your `User` class must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise property change notifications properly.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: @HighCore Ok, this worked, thanks!!! You can post this as an answer, and I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Your User class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise property change notifications properly.

-[HighCore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643085/highcore)

(This question needed an answer to be appropriately marked as "answered".)